# Notation for spiccato?

Tags: notation, strings, violin

An [older revision of Wikipedia article on Spiccato](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Spiccato&oldid=738418149) has an image showing what looks like a staccatissimo, with the caption "Notation for *spiccato*."

[image: spiccato]

I question that—it may be that strings can use spiccato to play staccatissimo, but that doesn't mean that staccatissimo = spiccato. Is Wikipedia correct? Is there *any* symbol used to indicate that a specific note should be played spiccato?

Comment: See this link: https://music.stackexchange.com/q/101884/6163

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spiccato, like most specific bowing techniques, is not often indicated explicitly in scores. The staccatissimo mark on that page does indeed often get translated as spiccato when given to a string player, but there are plenty of situations in which a regular staccato is interpreted as spiccato as well. Staccatissimo in Mozart, especially on repeated notes, is usually performed spiccato; Staccato dots in Bach, however, are often performed in the same way. I can certainly think of some situations where I've used spiccato even in situations with no markings at all, for example during a fast, repeated-note passage in music with a very light affect.

In other words, spiccato is more like a tool in a string player's interpretive tool chest--one that is very often effective for staccatissimo-marked passages. Of course, if the composer wishes to *ensure* that interpretive choice, they can add a written indication to that effect. That's the only explicit spiccato indication I've ever seen: either marked "spiccato" or "bouncing bow" or something to that effect.

Answer (score 3):

As always, I recommend  the [Dolmetsch](http://www.dolmetsch.com/musicalsymbols.htm) page, which in fact does not list a symbol for spiccato / sautille.  I think all the sheet music I've seen writes out the word over (or leading) the notes in question.